# How can I achieve the snapchat login look?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, stackview

On the log in page of snapchat, the button appears on top of the keyboard, I can do that but since the 6plus has a different size keyboard It cuts some of it off.

I have two textfields and two buttons all in a Vertical Stack View and I want the bottom of the vertical stack view to be on top of the top of the keyboard.

+
Also on the subject how can I add paddings on to content inside of the Vertical Stack View. It doesn't let me add constraints. As shown in the image below I want the TF to have like a space away from the screen and the button to remain full width.

216 is the height of the keyboard from the iPhone 6 and down, but on the 6 plus, which i found out later, is 226.

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Comment: Look into layout constraints. Either that or just create your views programatically

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this, and animate the view when an event is triggered.

```
// Get Screen Dimensions //
let screenHeight : Float = Float(view.bounds.height)
let screenWidth : Float = Float(view.bounds.width)
// Set Button View Height //
let buttonHeight : Float = 50.0

// Check Returned Screen Size //
if screenHeight == 667 {
    let login = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(screenHeight - (216.0 + buttonHeight)), CGFloat(screenWidth), CGFloat(buttonHeight)))
    login.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    view.addSubview(login)
} else if screenHeight == 736 {
    let login = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(screenHeight - (226.0 + buttonHeight)), CGFloat(screenWidth), CGFloat(buttonHeight)))
    login.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    view.addSubview(login)
}
```